# Cloud composer import custom plugin to all existing dags

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Cloud Composer to schedule multiple DAGs. These DAGs are built dynamically using [this method](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/) and they use custom plugins.

I would like to know how to proceed when adding / modifying a plugin which concerns all DAGs (let's say it adds a new task to each DAGs)?

Do we need to pause all the running DAGs when doing so?

What I did so far when adding /modifying a plugin, is :

- Upload the plugins into the `plugins` bucket of the Composer cluster (using gcloud composer command)
- Do a dummy update in the Airflow config -> add a dummy value to the airflow.cfg (using gcloud composer commands)

I did that to force the DAGs to pause, and once the update is finished then the DAGs are resumed but with the new plugins and hence the new tasks (or if its not in this dagrun then it's the next one). Is it useless?

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [architecture diagram](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture), the **Airflow webserver** where you view your DAG and plugin code runs in a Google-managed tenant project, whereas the **Airflow workers** which actually run your DAG and plugin code are directly in your project.

When a DAG/Plugin is placed in the [Composer bucket](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/managing-dags#adding_or_updating_a_dag), the Airflow webserver(which falls under tenant project) validates the code and updates any new scheduling changes in the Airflow database.

**At the same time**, the Airflow scheduler (in your project) asks the Airflow database for the next DAG to run and notifies the Airflow workers to perform the scheduled work. The Airflow workers (in your project) then grab the DAG/Plugin code from the Composer bucket and compile them in order to run that specific task.

Thus, any updates made to your DAGs/Plugin code is *read separately* by the Airflow webserver and Airflow workers, at different times.

- If you do not see your new code in the Airflow webserver, it should still be picked up by the Workers when they grab the code fresh on the new task run.
- Therefore you shouldn't have to restart Composer for the workers to pick up the changes.
- You cannot force a worker to grab and re-compile the new code mid task execution.

There are **two ways** to refresh the Airflow Webserver to see the Plugin code changes if it is not updating:

1. Set the `reload_on_plugin_change` property to `True` in the `[webserver]` section via the ‘AIRFLOW CONFIGURATIONS OVERRIDE’ tab in the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/updating#updating_environments).
2. OR, you can specifically add/remove/update a PYPI Package via the ‘[PYPI PACKAGES](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package)’ Console tab. Non PYPI Package changes will not trigger the web server restart. Note this will also initiate an entire Composer environment restart which may take ~20 minutes.